# A phrase understood as a request to step aside to not block out the view/panorama you are looking at

Tags: phrase-request, slang, colloquial-language

What may be the phrase, playful or polite, that when heard by the one it is addressed to, tells him/her that they are blocking out the sight you are looking at?

For example, in Russian, it is a question which may be translated into English as "Are you made of glass?" What are the most popular/common English colloquial or slang equivalents of it? I don't think there may be too many of them.

Comment: user3169 provides one version; I have always heard it as _**You make a better door than a window.**_

Comment: @P.E.Dant - Thank you very much. A penpal of mine suggested, "Was your father a glass maker?" She's not a native English speaker, though. Is anything like this in use in GB?

Comment: Tthere's nothing like that in English. A pity, because it's marvelous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are probably many, but one I grew up with is:

> You make a poor window.

Comment: +1. I'm sure someone has grown up with *Move out of the way, or I'll punch out your lights*..

Comment: Ha-ha! This is a really good one; thanks a million.

Comment: @TRomano You omitted the standard introductory phrase: _"Hey dude..."_ Also, the customary word order is _punch your lights out._

Comment: @P.E. Dant. You're right that **out** normally comes at the end, but where I come from, it's often said how I said it above.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=punch+out+your+lights%2Cpunch+out+his+lights%2Cpunch+his+lights+out%2Cpunch+your+lights+out&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpunch%20out%20your%20lights%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpunch%20out%20his%20lights%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpunch%20his%20lights%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpunch%20your%20lights%20out%3B%2Cc0